# Plot trace of figure

Tags: matlab, plot, binary, matlab-figure

I have 11 binary datasets and I would like to generate a graph with the trace of the corresponding figures of the data-sets (all 297x258) with the y-axis and x-axis multiplied with a scale of (1.3*10^(-6)) and labelled 'Y-axis(μm)' and 'X-axis (μm)' respectively. The 11 datasets are stored in a cell (i.e. `data1{1}`,...`data1{11}`). Also if the plot can also label each trace with the name of the corresponding dataset it will be appreciated (i.e. `data1{1},...`).

[The binary data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6njsuvdajt1vx30/data1.mat?dl=0)

An example of the expected output: 
[image: expected output]

Comment: Is it different from your previous question?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Yes it is different but it does use the same data. I will add an image of the expected output which will hopefully clarify the question.

Comment: I have also edited the other question, thank you for highlighting the clarity issue. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what is _"the trace of the corresponding figures of the data-sets"_? or simply, how do you get from `data1{1,1}` to the red line in the figure you attached?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question. Essentially I would like to plot a line around the edges of the corresponding images of data1{1},...data1{11}. In order to plot the image and see what it looks like I use:   figure, imshow(no_cracks_crack1_map)    The red line corresponds to the edge of data1{1} with the edges of data1{2}...data1{11} also mapped on the image. These datasets have the number of pixels in the y-axis and x-axis and multiplying these axis with (1.3*(10^(-6)) changes these axis's from the number of pixels to a measure of distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot this I start with finding the first non zero element in each column for all datasets, and then sum them up to plot the lines on top of each other.
Finally, I multiply the axis by the conversion constant you gave (`raitio` below) and change the format to meet your requested style:

```
data = reshape(cell2mat(data1),297,258,[]);
S = size(data);
fnzc = zeros(S([1 3])); % first non zero in column
for k = 1:S(3)
    csc = cumsum(data(:,:,k)>0,2); % on columns
    fnzc(:,k) = csc(:,end);
end
ratio = 1.3*(10^(-6));
ax = axes;
plot(ax,(S(1):-1:1)*ratio,cumsum(fnzc,2)*ratio)
ax.XAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%2d';
ax.XAxis.Exponent = -6;
ax.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%2d';
ax.YAxis.Exponent = -6;
```

And the result is:

[image: trace figure]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Would it be possible to change the axis so both are of the order of (1x10^-6) i.e. along X-axis 50*20(-6), 1*10^(-6),...400*10^(-6) and same for Y-axis. Thanks.

Comment: @a.kk I have multiplied both axes by  `1.3*(10^(-6))`, and since the true values are `0:300` and `0:3000` in the x- and y-axis respectively, you get axis in order of 10^-4 and 10^-3. If you want to get smaller values, you can multiply by a smaller number (e.g `1.3*(10^(-8))`) but is it about the values or about the way they display? i.e. instead of 0.5 on the axis and a small x10^-4 in the corner, placing a label of `0.5*10^-6` on the axis.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, it was about the way they were displayed. Thank you for updating the answer.

Comment: @a.kk so now it's fine? or you want the `10^-6` to show on each label? Personally, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: It's great now. Thanks.